# Turning a CSS With Lots of Margins & Paddings into a Responsive Design

Tags: css, margin, padding

I am new to coding and I have created a website with lots of margin and padding values. So is there a logical way to make it responsive?

Comment: Always aim to use percentages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Margin and padding shouldn't really matter when it comes to making a responsive site. To make a site responsive, one of the big things is working on making the site width's into percentages. Also, finding a good framework can help a lot. I would suggest looking into bootstrap or foundation.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview

Comment: Yes I use Bootstrap grid system but the design is kinda more visual. So I had to write margins and padding values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply new margins and paddings inside Bootstrap breakpoints.
Pick only the one you need.

Some tips how to reduce amount of responsive code:

- Group elements which resize in the same way with one classname, then apply new sizes only for the group of the same classname.
- Apply responsive size for columns, like `col-xs-12`, `col-sm-6`, `col-md-4`
- Don't re-style all elements for every breakpoint, if you don't have to. Check if a website is looking good on a big screen, then resize browser and restyle only this elements which break on a smaller screen.
- Reduce the number of breakpoints to minimum, for example: 1. mobile devies, 2. tablets, 3. desktops.

css:

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you so much!